# Volume emission not working in blender 2.8 eevee

Tags: rendering, light, shaders, lighting, eevee-render-engine

I got this fire shader a while back. from what I can remember it worked in eevee but now it doesn't. also a normal emission shader in the volume is not working either.

any suggestions?[image]

Comment: *I can remember it worked in eevee*, I'm going to need a source for that. Also, do you mean 2.8 in the title?

Comment: Oops yes, here a source. i followed this tut when it came out and it worked perfectly https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1PdLIKr4Vjo

Comment: Did u activate "Bloom"?
I know nothing about this shader, but I know only one - emission need this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update blender 2.8 and it worked again so most likely a bug.